# Why can I not access one .Net Core project from another if the referrer references .Net 4.5?

Tags: .net

I created two projects in VS 2015.  Both of which were created as Class Library (Package), which generates .Net Core assemblies.  In one of these projects, I removed the reference to .Net 4.5.1, so it would be strictly Core.  From the other one, I added a reference to the Core only project, only to be given this compile time error.

The dependency TestCoreProject 1.0.0 in project TestWindowsProject does not support framework .NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1.

Why would this be an issue?  If I had tried to reference the .Net project from the Core one, that should not work, but the .Net one should not balk at referencing the Core project.

Comment: In the project properties, what is the Target framework for TestCoreProject?

Comment: `Class Library (Package)` isn't Core, it's a regular class library packaged as a NuGet package. Removing references to .NET 4.5.1 assemblies (which ones anyway?) doesn't make it Core either. Core is a different framework altogether with a different architecture and type system. You can't mix the two

Comment: There is no Target Framework, as this is not a traditional .Net project.  When you use the Class Library (Package) option to create the project, you do not get the same Project Properties that you would with a full .Net application.  This is the kind of project that has a project.json, which lists dotnet5.4 as its only framework.

Comment: Panagiotis, are you sure about that?  This option was added with a recent Update to VS 2015.  The project has a project.json, instead of the traditional xml based proj file.  I can only reference other projects that were similarly created using Class Library (Package).  I am completely blocked from adding references to projects that were created with the old Class Library project template.  Is there any place I can go to get a better understanding of the difference between dnxcore50 and dotnet5.4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out, but VS was not helpful.  When VS adds a project reference, it gets added to the main dependencies in project.json.  What I really want is to only reference the Core library when compiling against Core.  I can do that by manually moving the referene up into the dotnet5.4 section.

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net451": { },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "TestCoreProject": "1.0.0-*"
      }
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {

  }
```

From here I can use preprocessor directives in my code.  Ultimately, after learning about all of this through trial and error, I think what I really want is to reference both frameworks in all of my libraries, though.